# Implementing priority search in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to implement custom search in elastic search.

Problem statement is consider 3 documents inserted into elastic search with "names" field as array:

```
{
   id:1,
   names:["John Wick","Iron man"]
}
{
   id:2,
   names:["Wick Stone","Nick John"]
}
{
   id:3,
   names:["Manny Nick","Stone cold"]
}
```

when I search for "Nick" I want to boost or give priority to document starting with Nick so in this case document with id 2 should come first and then document with id 3 and also if I search for whole name "Manny Nick"
    doc with id 3 should be given priority.

Answer (score 0):

In such case, you may want to **modify/boost** the **score** of search matched result for required criteria. For example, match the documents with names `"Nick"` and at the same time modify and boost the score of documents which contains `names` that start with `Nick` so that documents that match `Nick` and also starts with `Nick` will have higher **score**.

One of the way to achieve this is using [Function Score Query.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)
In the below query, search is made for keyword "Nick" and matched documents' score is modified and boosted for criteria ***"names that start with Nick"*** using [Match Phrase Prefix Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) with additional weight 20.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "names": "Nick"
        }
      },
      "boost": "1",
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
              "names": "Nick"
            }
          },
          "weight": 20
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

Testing:

Inserted data:

```
{
   id:1,
   names:["John Wick","Iron man"]
}
{
   id:2,
   names:["Wick Stone","Nick John"]
}
{
   id:3,
   names:["Manny Nick","Stone cold"]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "took": 10,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 20.693148,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stack_1",
                "_type": "1",
                "_id": "T9kn5WsBrk7qsVCmKBGH",
                "_score": 20.693148,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "names": [
                        "Wick Stone",
                        "Nick John"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stack_1",
                "_type": "1",
                "_id": "Ttkm5WsBrk7qsVCm2RF_",
                "_score": 20.287682,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "names": [
                        "Manny Nick",
                        "Stone cold"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Will give it a try

Comment: it seems like not working i am getting same score for both records
screen shot for reference
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkyEM.png

Comment: do i need to change any settings or mappings for to deal with arrays
@ra-ka

Comment: @user3863788 I have tested in default mapping setting and I am getting the result right. So, I guess you don't need to change anything in mapping for array since it is simply `String` type (you have to in case it is object type). I have simply inserted test data as you have provided and tested with above query, and i am getting the result right. I will update answer for what I did to test with.

Comment: I think elastic search saves names fields like this.
For doc with id 2
names :   Wick Stone Nick John 

and for doc 3 
names:    Manny Nick Stone cold

so what i need is when i search for "Nick" i want to give boost to doc with id 2
as "Nick john" is a complete name of a person and it starts with "Nick" at the same time i dont want to ignore doc with id 3 as it contains "Nick"  @ra-ka

Comment: @user3863788 in that case you can still provide multiple filters with different weight for your required criteria. e.g. provide filter with higher weight in case name starts with "Nick" and provide filter with lower weight in case "Nick" exist/or part of the text.